# Filling a matrix with rows

Tags: java, android, arrays, matrix, rows

I'm trying to fill in a matrix with rows. I'm reading data in real time and I need to fill in the matrix with the first 256 values, then with the next 256 values, etc... Here's what I have so far but when I print it in console it shows me the object, not the matrix, so I don't know if I'm doing it right.

```
            transformed[0] = scaleEMG(transformed[0]);
            transformed[1] = scaleEDA(transformed[1]);
            transformed[2] = scaleAccelerometer(transformed[2]);
            transformed[3] = scaleAccelerometer(transformed[3]);
            transformed[4] = scaleAccelerometer(transformed[4]);


            double[][] buff = new double[256][6];

            for(int f=0;f<256;f++){
                    buff[f] = transformed;
            }

            Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(buff));
```

transformed gives me array by array of the reading of my sensors in a row, like this:

[image: transformed reading]
I just need to group these data in an array of 256x6. Then update this array (or another one) with the next 256 values and so on.

EDIT: I changed `toString` to `deepToString` and I defined my global variables and updated buff like this:

```
public static int f = 0;
public static double[][] buff = new double[256][6];

if(f<256){buff[f++]=transformed;}
```

But I'm always getting the same matrix, how can I fix this? As I said, the first matrix printed should be the first 256 values of transformed, the second matrix should be the next 256 values of transformed, etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "when I print it in console it shows me the object"? [edit] your question to show some example output.

Comment: issue is because you are currently assigning same array to your inner 2d arrays `buff[f] = transformed` , what exactly you expect , provide more info

Comment: if I print transformed it gives me an array with the reading of my sensores. I'm reading 1000 samples per second and it prints me each sample. Am I making mysefl clear? I buff I need to store the first 256 samples, so the first 256 readings of transformed, and then the next 256 and so on..

Comment: many things are still clear like how you are fetching data and when and where but the simple thing is, you should be doing something like `buff[f] = first 1d array` where `f-0` then `buff[f] = second 1d array` where `f-1` and so on. i am sensing you might need to keep a global variable and use it like `buff[f++]=transformed`  then later when `transformed` got the next values so `buff[f++]=transformed`

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying but I don't know how to actually do it. I should change buff[f] for buff[f++]?

Comment: if i am thinking what you are trying to say , eliminate the loop and use `buff[f++]=transformed` and make sure `f` and `buff` are assailable and set `f=0`

Comment: but how do i guarantee it fills it until 256?

Comment: you can use `if` condition like `if(f<256){buff[f++]=transformed;}`

Comment: I did it like this: `int f = 0; if(f<256){buff[f++]=transformed;}` but it only prints me zeros.

Comment: as i said `f` should be global in your class , if you declare it as a `local` variable then it will always be `0` and `buff` should also be global in current class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Arrays#deepToString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])) instead of `Arrays.toString` to print 2d array

```
Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + Arrays.deepToString(buff));
```

because it's like a object containing object

**Arrays#deepToString**

> Returns a string representation of the "deep contents" of the
>   specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, the
>   string representation contains their contents and so on. `This method is designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings`.

Comment: Thank you, I got to see what I'm getting

Comment: I'm still not getting what I need, I updated the question for you to understand better

Comment: @user8559076 still unclear how you are getting `transformed` array but as i said you need to assign your array to first index of `buff` and second time to second `index` of `buff` and make sure every time you get a new `transformed` array instead of changing the values of already created array

Comment: Transformed is reading data in real time, 1000 samples per second, so it prints me each sample read in console. That whay it gives me. I'm doing that but I don't know how to guarantee that i'm not replacing the values of transformed every time. How can I do that? I mean, transformed is simply a 1D array, I just need to group 256 of those 1D arrays in buff

Comment: @user8559076 it only happens, when you are storing the same array in 2d array by just changing it's values

Comment: i told you many many times , you need to new 1d array every time you want to store it in your 2d array , kindly learn the basics of 2d array and references in java